# How do I wait for networking before running a script?

Tags: networking, startup

I have a .bashrc file and inside it I have added the line `~/bin/startup2.sh`. This works fine if I open a terminal after startup. But when I open a terminal on reboot like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36466500/on-raspberry-pi-auto-start-terminal-after-login), I get an error that looks like it is related to networking.

> google.auth.exceptions.TransportError: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed (_ssl.c:600)

Is there a way to delay the execution of this script until I get networking?

This is using a Raspberry Pi 3 B

Comment: @Time4Tea I can't see any signature that it would be a networking problem. The question is unclear, because the OP didn't say (and he probably can't even say), what is in his `startup2.sh`, but I think it is not a dupe.

Answer (score 0):

In a script you can use if condition by mentioned until network is up. it should start

use if condition logic

Comment: Any chance you have the thing I need to put in the if statement?